# Generic PHP <=> Javascript command framework?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Are there any frameworks with "all the boilerplate" code written, helping to streamline PHP <=> JS (aka "AJAX") communication?

I'm assuming the are such libs written, but the ones I find are

1. [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/), which is JS <=> JS
2. Drupal's built in [ajax.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7), which can't easily be used in a non-Drupal project.

Other suggestions?

Comment: jQuery has nice abstraction for ajax.

Comment: What kind of framework are you looking for? Ajax is merely straight forward and it depends more on what you transmit and do then instead of just the protocol/transport.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have mentioned: use jQuery's `$.ajax` for JS side, and `json_encode` and `json_decode` for your PHP side. Not really much more to it than that.

Answer (score 0):

I like Ext Direct from Sencha.

To be used with Ext JS.